# OpenSSL 1.0.1 on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, openssl

My app runs on Ruby 2.0.0 built against OpenSSL 1.0.1c for AES-GCM support. Heroku appears to be using OpenSSL 0.9.8k (see https://twitter.com/sferik/status/314495375555829760). Is there any way to upgrade to 1.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to create a custom buildpack.

You need to build a version of Ruby linked against the correct version of OpenSSL that will run on Heroku's system. For this, you need to use either a local 64-bit Linux system or a Heroku buildserver. Vulcan has problems building Ruby specifically, so the best way to do this in the absence of an appropriate local machine is to use [Heroku push](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push) from an empty directory with a source-based buildpack. Then you can extract the binaries from the resulting slug and use them with a much faster binary buildpack.

I've [posted my buildpack here](https://github.com/gtank/ossl-buildpack). It is currently working and provides Ruby 2.0.0 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e.