# Deploying RoR app with GMP to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gmp

I am trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails app using the GMP library for crypto. Everything works fine in development.

When I git push to Heroku or Openshift here is the error message I get:

```
remote: Installing gmp (0.5.47) with native extensions .........
remote: 
remote: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote: 
remote:         /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
remote: checking for gmp.h... no
remote: can't find gmp.h, try --with-gmp-include=<path>
remote: checking for __gmpz_init() in -lgmp... no
remote: can't find -lgmp, try --with-gmp-lib=<path>
remote: checking for mpfr.h... no
remote: checking for SIZEOF_INTPTR_T... yes
remote: *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote: Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
remote: necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
remote: details.  You may need configuration options.
```

As it turns out, Heroku support admitted their stack image does not include GMP yet.
They suggested I write my own buildpack to include the GMP library on the production server.
I have no clue even after looking at a [custom buildpack for OpennSSL here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269445/openssl-1-0-1-on-heroku).
Any advice is welcome.