# Heroku openssl version not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, openssl, buildpack

I am trying to get my application to use OpenSSL v 1.0.1e instead of the default OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009 on Heroku.  I've added in a .buildpacks file which looks like:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
https://github.com/gtank/ossl-buildpack.git
```

I've also added in the buildpack url:

```
BUILDPACK_URL:               https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
```

When I push to heroku, I see the following:

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
...
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/gtank/ossl-buildpack.git
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby with OpenSSL 1.0.1e
-----> Fetching OpenSSL binaries
-----> Got OpenSSL binaries
```

However, when I run openssl version on heroku run bash, I still see OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009 instead of OpenSSL 1.0.1e.  Would anyone happen to know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenSSL 1.0.1 on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269445/openssl-1-0-1-on-heroku)

Comment: I tried that solution and it didn't work for me.  You can see I even used his buildpack.