# Upgrade OpenSSL on Heroku

Tags: python, ssl, heroku, openssl, python-requests

I am using the python stack on Heroku and am trying to use the requests library to access an https API that uses TLS 1.2

I have got thing working on my local environment by upgrading openssl to 1.0.1 and I need to do the same thing in my Heroku environment.

Here is the error in Heroku and I've confirmed that the openssl version is OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno bad handshake] [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]
```

Is there a python buildpack that can support this? It looks like there is a ruby buildpack, but I haven't seen it verified to work [OpenSSL 1.0.1 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269445/openssl-1-0-1-on-heroku)

I tried to mimic that behavior, but don't really know what I'm doing with a fork of the standard python buildpack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cedar-14, has OpenSSL 1.0.1f. Heroku-16, the most recent Heroku stack, has OpenSSL 1.0.2g. [Stack package details](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-ubuntu-packages)

The upgrade guide is here: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration